# Cannot superimpose one parallel coordinate plot over another using GGally package (and ggplot2) package in R

Tags: r

I am using the ggparcoord() function of the GGally package in R to create a Parallel Coordinate Plot of the iris data (Present in R). I used the following code

`ggparcoord(data=iris, columns=1:4 , groupColumn=5,alpha=I(0.3))+theme_light()+theme(legend.position="none")` .

Now I have calculated median of the four variables (Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width) separately for the three species (setosa,versicolor,virginica) and using this information I have created a new data.

Here is the data (I have named the data as med)

```
  |Sepal.Length|    Sepal.Width |Petal.Length | Petal.Width | Species
-----------------------------------------------------------------
  |         5   |         3.4   |      1.5    |    0.2      |  1
  |        5.9  |         2.8   |     4.35    |    1.3      |  2
  |        6.5  |         3     |     5.55    |      2      |  3
```

Here 1 denotes setosa, 2 denotes versicolor and 3 denotes virginica. Using this data I have again created a Parallel coordinate plot. The code is:

`ggparcoord(data=med,columns=1:4, groupColumn=5)+theme_light()` .

I now wish to superimpose this plot over the previous plot. To do so I tried using

`p<-ggparcoord(data=iris, columns=1:4 , groupColumn=5,alpha=I(0.3))
p+ggparcoord(data=med,columns=1:4, groupColumn=5)+theme_light()` .

But this gives me an error of the following type

"Error: Don't know how to add o to a plot".

Please help me resolve this problem.

Thank You in advance for taking out time to look at my question.

Souradeep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you need to create a dataset that combines both your summary information and the raw data.  I use `dplyr` to create the summary by species, give it an `alpha` value, then bind it back with the original `iris` dataset with an added `alpha` value.

The resultant plot shows the raw data as very transparent, and the summarized median as non-transparent.  You can adjust this for linetype, color, etc.

```
library(dplyr)
library(GGally)
library(ggplot2)

med <- iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(median)) %>% 
  mutate(alpha = 1) %>% 
  bind_rows(mutate(iris, alpha = 0.1))

ggparcoord(data = med, columns = 2:4 , groupColumn = 1, alpha = "alpha") + 
  theme_light() + 
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image]